# CakePHP use Regex variable capture in routes?

Tags: cakephp, mod-rewrite, routes, cakephp-1.3

In my CakePHP app I have static pages set up like this:

```
Router::connect(
    '/terms', 
    array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'terms')
);
```

This will rewrite `/terms` to `/pages/display/terms` To make prettier shorter URLs.

Now If I wanted to do this for all my static pages, it would get quite redundant:

```
Router::connect(
    '/terms', 
    array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'terms')
);
Router::connect(
    '/privacy', 
    array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'privacy')
);
Router::connect(
    '/about', 
    array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'about')
);
```

With regular mod_rewrite you can do something like this:

```
/(terms|privacy|about) /pages/display/$1
```

So I naturally attempted this:

```
Router::connect(
    '/(terms|privacy|about)', 
    array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', '$1')
);
```

It does not work. Is there support for something like this, if so how do you do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just off the top of my head, this may solve the issue. To perform a regex match on a portion you need to do so like this:

```
Router::connect(
    '/:page',
    array(
        'controller' => 'pages',
        'action' => 'display',
    ),
    array(
        'page' => '(terms|privacy|about)',
        'pass' => array('page')
    )
);
```

Notice how the `page` placeholder in the URL gets extrapolated on in the third parameter, the array. In there we say that it must match the provided regular expression. Also of note is that it also says to pass the `page` placeholder to the `action` method. That way it knows which page to render.

Comment: I am trying to understand what is happening here. In the first param `/:page` What does the colon mean?

Comment: Basically the colon is a placeholder. If the name is "controller" or "action", Cake will know how to map that. In this case however we're using our own, custom name of `page` and then later on in the method we're saying "Page must match this regex to be valid" if it's not valid, the route isn't matched.